# socket.io laravel echo not working in production in ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, socket.io, laravel-echo

I'm using socket.io and laravel echo server with Redis and also SSL installed on the server but the socket.io file is not loading on the production ubuntu server everything works fine in my local window I'm not sure if I need any other configurations for production I also allow UFW 6001 port.

this is my laravel-echo-server.json file.

```
{
"authHost": "https://flowerful.initialengine.com",
"authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
"clients": [
    {
        "appId": "bb6e18dd7fd2e7aa",
        "key": "c52b04fae249d3cb303b317b281b1599"
    }
],
"rejectUnauthorized": false,
"database": "redis",
"databaseConfig": {
    "redis": {},
    "sqlite": {
        "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
    }
},
"devMode": true,
"host": null,
"port": "3001",
"protocol": "https",
"socketio": {},
"secureOptions": 67108864,
"sslCertPath": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/flowerful.initialengine.com/fullchain.pem",
"sslKeyPath": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/flowerful.initialengine.com/privkey.pem",
"sslCertChainPath": "",
"sslPassphrase": "",
"subscribers": {
    "http": true,
    "redis": true
},
"apiOriginAllow": {
    "allowCors": true,
    "allowOrigin": "https://flowerful.initialengine.com",
    "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
    "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
}
```

}

[image: this is laravel echo server running on the production server.]

I search on different portals and get some help and I apply some things following.

1. Allow ufw port 6001
2. run command `laravel-echo-server init` and create a config file
3. give SSL the right paths

Some things in my mind may be happening.
I installed virtual host may be apache2 not allow the domain to run on 6001 port

the URL is that is not working.

`https://flowerful.initialengine.com:6001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NLFfgwB`

[image]

[image: Console window browser]

Comment: please take a photo from your console browser, maybe it's a cross-origin error?

Comment: make sure ports are open or firewall don't block requests.

Comment: port 6001 is open

Comment: are you using Cloudflare or somethings like?

Comment: Console browser photo attached. @No.The.Hi

Comment: I'm using digital ocean droplet @No.The.Hi

Comment: @KamranMalik, I'm also facing the same issue with digital ocean droplet. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: @BelloDamilola yes i fixed you need to make sure your laravel-echo-server.json is correct by following steps
1: SSL is enabled and add right paths in sslCertPath, sslKeyPath
2: make sure authHost is your domain like https://example.com not any domain/route
3: make sure you added your domain in apiOriginAllow.allowOrigin
4: you should use https in paths

Comment: Check my post for your solution

Answer (score 1):

I think you should generate and set the right SSL file with `.cert` and '.key' extension for `laravel-echo-server` config like this:

```
"sslCertPath": "/{path_of_ssl}/flowerful.initialengine.com.cert.combined",
"sslKeyPath": "/{path_of_ssl}/flowerful.initialengine.com.key",
```

Comment: i have 4 paths available in /etc/letsencrypt/live/flowerful.initialengine.com
cert.pem
chain.pem
fullchain.pem
privkey.pem

Comment: Ssl error gone now im getting index.js:133 GET https://flowerful.initialengine.com:6001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NLFsCGo net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT this error @No. The.Hi

Comment: I have not worked with Droplet so far and I don't know how does it work but I think it has closed the port!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, just port 6001 was closed.
Check on server is project serve on your port:

```
curl -I localhost:6001
```

If you receive http headers, that mean is all **ok** and you need just open port.

For open port:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 6001 --syn -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is not a port problem on the server then you can do this my personal experience test.

What I would personally do is use an Nginx server as a reverse proxy. That way you could install an SSL certificate via Nginx and then proxy the traffic to the Laravel echo server.

The proxy rule would look as follows:

```
location /ws/{

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6001/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}
```

Then rather than using `https://your_domain:6001` in your frontend, you would use `https://your_domain/ws` which would internally proxy the traffic to the echo server.

Let me know how it goes!

If you want to learn more about the [production](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server/blob/master/README.md)